# Rails Associations references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

am trying to build a small application to sell tickets with PayPal. We have two types of tickets for an Event, Standard and VIP tickets.

What I want to achieve is when the user visits event/show page, clicks on a buy ticket button, then he is directed to a payment page with the option to select the ticket type he wishes to buy and then checkout.

I am confused about how to set the associations between the model.

This is what I have so far

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tickets
end


class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ticket

end


class User < ApplicationRecord

 end


class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  enum type: [ :standard, :vip ]
  belongs_to :event
end
```

What is the best options to create the relationship between the Events, Tickets and TicketType and what references should exit in their databases

Comment: I think it is better to store ticket types as field in the Ticket model. You can use an enumerator for it. Just create an integer field 'type' and use `enum type: [:standard, :vip]` in the Ticket model

Comment: I guess `Payment` should `belongs_to :ticket` instead of `:event`, becoming the join table between `Ticket` and `User`. `Ticket` should `belongs_to :event`. Agree with Vasilisa in case of few kind of tickets, but consider the option of having more in future.

Comment: ok, so what will be the relationship between the User and the Event and the ticket. Should the user have many Tickets? I want to save the users tickets in the database when they purchase a tickets?

Answer (score 0):

You´re on the right track - what you need is just an association between users and tickets and indirect associations to tie it together.

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :users, through: :tickets
end

class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ticket
  has_one :event, through: :ticket
  has_one :user, through: :ticket
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :payments, through: :tickets
  has_many :events, through: :tickets
end


class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  enum level: [ :standard, :vip ]
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :payments
end
```

Using a `has_many` association between tickets and payments is a good call as it lets you handle keeping track of failed payments.

But you should beware of using the name `type` for an enum or any other type of column in ActiveRecord as it has a special significance since its used to infer the class to be loaded in polymorphic associations or STI - it can have unintended consequences.

Comment: Thanks very much. @max. what is the best way to set the price for an event, Is it t through the Event table or through the price table. So should the event table have a price column or the ticket table should have a price column? I want to give the user the option to select the ticket type he wants to purchase. either VIP or standard. so how can you set different prices for the event through the enum record

Comment: I think you should put price columns on both. If the ticket price fluctuates you should keep track of the current price for the event and also how much the customer paid for their ticket. Oh and remember to use a decimal type for the columns - not floats.